# Spring JPA Repository Null Parameters

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I have read some posts on having null values in repository requests, but they are all years old. So  I ask this question to get the current state of the problem.

What I am exactly talking about:

I want to have a JPA request with optional null values. A function in my repository would look like this:

```
public List<MyClass> filter(Integer param);
```

So that I can omit the parameter in the filter like this: (part of @Query)

```
(:param IS NULL OR param=:param)
```

This only works as long as my param is not NULL.

Pls note that I am using a native query here. (JPA implementation is Hibernate, DB is postgres)

Thanks in advance for every update!

Answer (score 1):

I looked at this issue fairly extensively.  Observations:

1. With custom queries using JPQL, you should be able to do something like this:

> ```
> @Query("select m from MyClass m where :param IS null OR m.param = :param")
> public List<MyClass> filter(@Param("param") Integer param);
> ```

assuming here of course that `param` is a well-defined property of a Spring entity named `MyClass`.

2. If you use native queries, then you need to supply a non-null value for `param`.  Eg:

> ```
> @Query(value = "select * from MyClass m where :param < 0 OR m.param = :param", nativeQuery = true)
> public List<MyClass> filter(@Param("param") Integer param);
> ```

In the event `param` is null-valued, you then would need to call `filter()` with `param` set to -1, for example.

I realize this is not so satisfying, and I suspect it speaks to some current limitations in Spring JPA.

Answer (score 0):

There is quick guide to NULL values in repository requests here:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-null-parameters

Comment: Also saw this, but this does not really help me. Could not make it work. Also, baeldung is using JPQL while I am using native queries.